# Object undefined angular

Tags: angularjs

```
// app.js
$scope.result = {};
//$scope.result = [];

for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
   $scope.result[i].value = object[i].value;
   $scope.result[i].justification = object[i].justification;
};
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

> `$scope.result[i] is "undefined"`

Comment: puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada? ambos ganan reputación. Ademas asi se sabe que preguntas están resueltas sin tener que entrar a leerlas :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes añadir propiedades a un objeto, sin antes crear el objeto en si:

```
$scope.result = {}

for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
   $scope.result[i] = { };
   $scope.result[i].value = object[i].value;
   $scope.result[i].justification = object[i].justification;
};
```

Comment: efectivamente era eso

Comment: @Trauma voy a ponerlo en la pregunta, para que elimines tambien :) aunque quizá el OP no se ha conectado o no tiene la app movil :¬(

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto `$scope.result = [];` en lugar de lo que tu tienes `$scope.result = {};`.

Comment: tb lo he probado pero no funciona